# My Azure regex not working as expected

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I am trying below code to find valid and not-valid names

```
string pattern = @"((?:[GE\-[RGrp]+))";
            foreach (var AzureResponse in Response)
            {

                if (AzureResponse.name!= null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1} a valid resource name.", AzureResponse.name, Regex.IsMatch(@AzureResponse.name, pattern) ? "is" : "Is not");


                }

            }
```

But it is printing out all the resources names are valid even though i know few are not, it seems i am not able to get the correct regex.

What i want is:

- any name which **starts** with *"GE-RGrp"*  should be valid one and rest are not valid

Comment: From the description you provide, wouldn't it be better to test for .StartsWith("GE-RGrp-") ?

Comment: This `[GE\-[RGrp]` is a character class with chars `G`,`E`,`-`,`[`,`R`,`G`,`r`,`p` quantified with `+`. So any group of characters with those letters/symbols will be matched. If going the regex route better use something like `\bGE-RGrp(\w+)` or `\b(GE-RGrp\w+)`

Comment: Try `@AzureResponse.name.StartsWith("GE-RGrp")`. No need to use a regex if you check if a string starts with a literal substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are set on using Regex, then `string pattern = @"^GE-RGrp";` should do the trick.